# Sort datatables by a field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I'm working with an mvc5 app and I'm using DataTables in my tables.
The problem is that I want to sort results by a field (ID) in descending order.
It works fine with normal tables but doesn't work if I use DataTables.

Here is my code

in Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var albarans = db.Albarans.Include(a => a.Obra).OrderByDescending(a=>a.ID);
    return View(albarans.ToList());
}
```

in View

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table').dataTable({
            "language": {

                "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                "sUrl":            "",
                "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst":    "Primero",
                        "sLast":     "Último",
                        "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                    },
                    "oAria": {
                        "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                    }
              }
         });
    });
</script>


<table id="table">
   ...
</table>
```

Comment: FYI, the word is "sort", not "short". "Short" means "not tall".

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table').dataTable({
            "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
            "language": {
```